# Add a system Icon in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, imaging

I have to add a system icon in a Datagrid column,The data grid is not free its with data generated from a datasource.

system icon can not be binded it should be added in the codebehind.

Comment: You could just add a Datatemplate image and use a binding converter to add the icon to the image.